# using average with group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three table

```
EMPLOYEE table with ID and NAME
COMPANY table with ID and NAME
and 
SALARY table with EMPLOYEE_ID, COMPANY_ID and SALARY
```

I wanted to print the name of every company where the average salary is greater than or equal to 40000

My query is

```
Select distinct COMPANY.NAME from COMPANY,SALARY,EMPLOYEE WHERE SALARY.COMPANY_ID=COMPANY.ID and (select avg(SALARY) from SALARY,EMPLOYEE WHERE SALARY.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPLOYEE.ID) >=40000;
```

Comment: We stopped writing queries this way in about 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 10):

You could group by the company name and have the condition in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT   c.name
FROM     company c
JOIN     salary s ON c.id = s.company_id
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING   AVG(salary) >= 40000
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY.NAME 
FROM COMPANY 
INNER JOIN SALARY ON COMPANY.ID = SALARY.COMPANY_ID 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.ID = SALARY.EMPLOYEE_ID 
GROUP BY COMPANY.NAME HAVING AVG(SAL)>=40000
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT T1.NAME
FROM COMPANY AS T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT COMPANY_ID, AVG(SALARY) AS avgSalary FROM SALARY GROUP BY COMPANY_ID) AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.COMPANY_ID
WHERE T2.avgSalary >= 40000;